# Division algebras over the reals

Tags: abstract-algebra

As is well known there are only three finite dimensional division algebras over the real numbers, namely: the real numbers themselves; the complex numbers and the quaternions. But what happens to algebras of infinite dimension?

Can we cosntruct an infinite dimensional division algebra over the reals? This algebra can be algebraic?

Comment: Fields of rational functions. The fields of meromorphic functions on connected complex manifolds. (These are transcendental over $\mathbb{R}$ of course.)

Comment: Thanks. There is an exemple of an division algebra $\mathbb D$ over the reals infinite dimensional but algebraic, that is, every elemento $a\in\mathbb D$  is algebraic over the reals?

Comment: In the commutative case, the only algebraic extension of $\mathbb{R}$ (except the trivial one) is $\mathbb{C}$ (up to isomorphism), since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. In the non-commutative case, I don't know. I suppose we still call an element $\alpha$ algebraic if there is a nonzero $p\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ with $p(\alpha) = 0$?

Comment: Regarding the intro to your question, there is at least one other finite dimensional division algebra over the reals: octonions.